# CardScrollViewAnimation Listener?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

I want to implement some small task or call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`
whenever the animation done by `mCardScrollView.animate(position, Animation.INSERTION);` 
is completed. So i was wondering is there a way to implement this.

Do i have to write my own animation callback for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`withEndAction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#withEndAction%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method to perform something you want to when animation is completed successfully.

```
Runnable endAction = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         //do something
     }
};

mCardScrollView.animate(position, Animation.INSERTION).withEndAction(endAction);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer will not work because this form of `CardScrollView.animate` returns a `boolean` rather than a `ViewPropertyAnimator`.

Comment: Yeah @TonyAllevato is Right